# Unsure whether to use Flexbox, tables, or rows and columns

Tags: css, html, flexbox

So I am trying to make a controller for an RC car that will work on any size screen, I plan on having the page of the app have up, down, left, right, and in the middle a stop, so sort of like a tv remote control look. I am newer to html and css and am just unsure what would be the best way to go about doing this. I want the buttons to autofit to the screen and fill it.
Any advice would be great.

Comment: i'd just go with flexbox.  if i'm not getting paid, IE10 and below can suck it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox support isn't great (http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). Tables are supported in all browsers, however, it really isn't the right solution; tables are designed for charts, not layout.

The best solution is to use responsive design techniques (min-width, max-width, % widths, etc) with divs. This should be compatible in IE9+ and all modern browsers. See http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/22/responsive-web-design-techniques-tools-and-design-strategies/, http://www.sitepoint.com/common-techniques-in-responsive-web-design/, or simply Google "Responsive Design" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would use none of the above.  I would use absolute positioning like this:

```
.up, .down, .left, .right, .stop { 
    position: absolute;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 33.3%;
}

.up {
    top: 0%;
    left: 33.3%
}

.right {
    top: 33.3%;
    left: 66.6%;
}
```

And so on.

This has the benefit of being compatible with every browser ever created by humans.

Comment: You don't really need absolute positioning to build a layout like this.

Comment: @Nit: Yes, you can do it without absolute positioning.  You can probably do it without any single technique that you could name.  Yet you have to pick one of them, and this is the best in my opinion.